# Batch rename filename with spaces using sed and for loop

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I wanted to rename these file such that **"Try Django 1.8 Tutorial -"** part is removed and only remaining part is left as file name eg. **"14 of 42 - Form in a View.mp4"** or **"14of42-ForminaView.mp4"**
here is the snippet of output of **ls** command :-

```
20.mp4 
24 of 42-CSS                                                                  
7 of 42 -  Django Settings Overview -  Learn Django.mp4
21.mp4
8 of 42 - Template Configuration -  Learn Django.mp4
26 of 42 - Styling MVP Landing Part 2 - Learn Django.mp4 
23-stylingmvplanding.mp4                                              
Try Django 1.8 Tutorial - 12 of 42  - Form Validation -  Learn Django.mp4
Try Django 1.8 Tutorial - 13 of 42  - View & Template Context -  Learn Django.mp4         
Try Django 1.8 Tutorial - 14 of 42 - Form in a View -  Learn Django.mp4             
Try Django 1.8 Tutorial - 16 of 42  - Setup Email - Learn Django.mp4
```

i tried with below sed and for loop but got errors:-

```
for ff in Try*; do mv $ff $(echo $ff | sed -e 's/Try Django 1.8 Tutorial -//g' -e 's/ //g')  ; done
mv: target ‘12of42-FormValidation-LearnDjango.mp4’ is not a directory
mv: target ‘13of42-View&TemplateContext-LearnDjango.mp4’ is not a directory
mv: target ‘14of42-ForminaView-LearnDjango.mp4’ is not a directory
```

Any idea to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need double-quotes around anything that is subject to word-splitting:

```
for ff in Try*; do mv "$ff" "$(echo "$ff" | sed -e 's/Try Django 1.8 Tutorial -//g' -e 's/ //g')"  ; done
```

#### What went wrong

Let's consider this file:

```
ff='Try Django 1.8 Tutorial - 16 of 42 - Setup Email - Learn Django.mp4'
```

and this command:

```
mv $ff $(echo $ff | sed -e 's/Try Django 1.8 Tutorial -//g' -e 's/ //g')
```

When the shell sees that command, it performs command substitution and finds:

```
mv Try Django 1.8 Tutorial - 16 of 42 - Setup Email - Learn Django.mp4 16of42-SetupEmail-LearnDjango.mp4
```

Since no double-quotes were used, word-splitting is also performed.  After word-splitting, the `mv` command has 14 arguments.  The first is `Try`, the second is `Django`, the third is `1.8`, and so on.  When given more than two arguments, `mv` expects to move a list of files (all the arguments except the last) to a target directory (the last argument).  Since the last argument is not a directory, it returns the error:

```
mv: target ‘16of42-SetupEmail-LearnDjango.mp4’ is not a directory
```

#### Alternate solution

This can also be done in pure shell:

```
for f in Try*; do out=${f/Try Django 1.8 Tutorial -/}; mv "$f" "${out// /}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

using [perl rename](http://man.cx/prename):

```
prename 's/Try Django 1.8 Tutorial - *//' *
```

Or sometimes, just,

```
rename  's/Try Django 1.8 Tutorial - *//' *
```